# dplyr/ggplot2: time plot with stacked bars containing na values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, na

How can I make a stacked barplot containing na values with dplyr and ggplot2?

x Axis: year
Y Axis: numbers of observations and numbers of NA

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
                     column2 = c(4, NA, 9, 1))


library (dplyr)

missing_data <- data %>%
                   count(year, complete.cases(column2))
```

My results

```
year    complete.cases(column2)     n
(dbl)                      (lgl) (int)
1  2015                   FALSE     1
2  2015                    TRUE     1
3  2016                    TRUE     2
```

what I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
na_plot  <- ggplot (missing_data, aes(x=year, y=n))  
na_plot+
geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = complete.cases(column2))
```

Comment: Would adding "group = complete.cases(column2)" inside the aes statement do the trick?

Comment: You can use back-ticks around non-syntactically valid names: \`complete.cases(column2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function `complete.cases` somehow interferes with the variable name. Try renaming (also `factor` the `year`):

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
                   column2 = c(4, NA, 9, 1))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

missing_data <- data %>%
   count(year, complete.cases(column2))

names(missing_data)[2] = "col2"   

na_plot <- ggplot(missing_data, aes(x=factor(year), y=n))
na_plot + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = col2))
```

Comment: It works great. I tried with dplyr rename function with no success. Can I change TRUE ou FALSE in the plot?

Comment: @Wilcar you mean like recoding variable levels? Try `?ifelse`.

Comment: How can I use ifelse?